# How to solve a problem using DensityPlot in a Hypergeometric function?

Tags: number-representation, plotting

The problem is to obtain a DensityPlot of a Hypergeometric function

The code is the following

```
 long = 532*10^-9;  k = N[(2 \[Pi])/long]; angl = Pi/5;  kt = 
 N[k  Sin[angl]] ;   a = 0; L=30; pp=100;

f[x_, y_] =   Abs[Exp[-I* kt*  Re[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2/2] Hypergeometric1F1[  
 1/4  - I*a/2, 1/2,I *kt*Re[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2] Exp[-I *kt * Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/4  + I*a/2, 1/2, I *kt*Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2]];

Xn = L/kt ;     Yn = L/kt;


DensityPlot[Abs[f[x, y]], {x, -Xn, Xn}, {y, - Yn, Yn},
PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> pp, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], Exclusions -> None] 


Plot3D[Abs[f[x, y]], {x, -Xn, Xn}, {y, - Yn, Yn}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> pp, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y},LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], ViewPoint -> {1.4, -2.0, 1.8},Exclusions -> None]
```

The output works fine if kt=1,

The idea is to do Xn and Yn is to "normalize or rescale" by this parameter, 
I also try by changing Xn = long L;   Yn = long L;

Unfortunately, the desire result plot cannot be obtained [image] Similar plots can be obtained using Xn and Yn, Here are the plots using the code above but for this case  kt=1.

Thanks for your help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your problems are caused by using machine precision. Using exact values:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

long = 532*10^-9;
k = (2 π)/long;
angl = Pi/5;
kt = k Sin[angl];
a = 0;
L = 30;
pp = 100;

f[x_, y_] = Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
   Abs[Exp[-I*kt*Re[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2/2]*
       Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 - I*a/2, 1/2,
        I*kt*Re[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2]*
       Exp[-I*kt*Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2]* 
       Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 + I*a/2, 1/2,
        I*kt*Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)]^2]] //
     ComplexExpand // FullSimplify];

fAbs[x_, y_] = Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
  Abs[f[x, y]] //
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
   FullSimplify]

(* 1250 (10 - 2 Sqrt[5])^(1/4) Sqrt[(10 π)/133]
  Abs[Sqrt[y]
    BesselJ[-(1/4), 
    62500000/133 Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] π Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2] BesselJ[-(1/
     4), 62500000/133 Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] π Re[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2]] Gamma[
  3/4]^2 *)
```

**EDIT**

```
DensityPlot[
 fAbs[x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 MaxRecursion -> 15,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Axes -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {x, y},
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[
 fAbs[x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 MaxRecursion -> 15,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, None},
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, the range must be between -30 and 30

Comment: I use the following command DeleteCases, but the plot does not properly DensityPlot figures that the function is zero and the small values are due to rounding noise. I try using the following DeleteCases[ DensityPlot[fAbs[x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, {# 1000 &, #/1000 &}}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 150, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, FrameTicks -> True, Exclusions -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic], ScalingFunctions -> _, Infinity] but, the output plot is wrong, but the range plot is according to the initial conditions.

Comment: The images are not uploading but the code should display them.

Comment: I check the problem again with your solution and the solution is written below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [image]

```
 DensityPlot[fAbs[x, y], {x, - Xn, Xn}, {y, - Yn, Yn}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> pp, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Axes -> True, FrameTicks -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(x\), \(kt\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(y\), \(kt\)]\)"},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], Exclusions -> None]
```

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comments. Your first comment on my answer stated "the range must be between -30 and 30" and the second comment gave the plot range as "{x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}". Your answer does not comply with this condition.

Comment: Your comment is correct. It was a misunderstanding, my apologies. The range valid must be when  Xn = L/kt;   and     Yn = L/kt;  and L=30. where,  kt   is defined above.